# c# unverifiable code without unmanaged permission

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, appdomain

I have a .net assembly with a method that is not verifiable.

I am trying to load this assembly in a sandbox appdomain.

If I load with skip verification, but not with Unmanaged I get a verification exception. Like so:

```
new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution | 
                       SecurityPermissionFlag.SkipVerification);
```

If I load with unmanaged permission it works, but then the app domain won't be enough "sandboxed".

```
new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution | 
                       SecurityPermissionFlag.SkipVerification |
                       SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode);
```

Also - I am running .Net 4, and to make the above to work I had to switch to transperancy model level 1, like so:

```
[assembly:SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
```

So, my question is:

1. Is there a way to run unverified code without UnamangedCode permission.
2. Is there a way to make the above work with Level2 security ruleset.

Thanks!

Comment: An application is either sandboxed or its not. So what does ` won't be enough sandboxed` mean exactly?  It sounds like you need to get an assembly that is verifiable instead of trying to create workaround.

Comment: In this sandbox I need to protect the user from himself, and not against some potential threat. That's why I am not worried about unverifiable code. But I am worried about Unmanaged code. Anyways, I can not get it verifiable because of some .net frameworks I use.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to run unverified code without UnamangedCode
>   permission.

Even if there was, you would have given up any security at that point. Unverifiable code has the same power as unmanaged code. It allows you to break the type system for example.

It makes not sense to have SkipVerification and not UnmanagedCode (or the other way around). The two are equivalent and I consider it to be a bug in the framework that both exist.